# Can I use Steam in home streaming with windows 10 without a physical display attached?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, resolution, steam, headless

Without a physical display attached, Windows 10 defaults to a 1024x768 display even though it has a very capable video card attached.

When i connect with RDC, windows is willing to connect at, say, 1920x1200, but if i try to stream a game with Steam, i will get the notification that the display is locked. If i use VNC, I can't set the display resolution higher than 1024x768.

I can solve this problem with a hardware display emulator, but what I want to know if there a way with software to create a virtual display in windows 10 with arbitrary resolution that will work with in-home streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Powerstrip from Entech Taiwan http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm is what you need to fake windows into thinking there is a monitor connected. You will set your resolution in there.

Also when disconnecting from Remote Desktop you will need to run a script such as this to not lock the screen (so games can start): tscon %sessionname% /dest:console. I suggest creating a shortcut on the desktop.

Comment: thank you, i did indeed try this and was unable to get powerstrip to correctly emulate a monitor in windows 10. If you have done this, i would be interested in hearing more. I ended up buying an hdmi terminator and use tightvnc to connect to it. So far, everything has been great, but i was never able to get powerstrip and remote desktop to provide this sort of behavior consistently in windows 10.